# How to execute odoo shell from inside of docker container properly?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, odoo, odoo-13

I'm trying to use shell inside docker container with odoo and I have some problems.

I set up my local environment via docker-compose, more precisely, I am running odoo and PostgreSQL in one network, but when I want to specify db for odoo shell, it doesn't work.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
    - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
    - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  odoo:
    depends_on:
    - db
    build: .
    ports:
    - '8069:8069'
    - '8071:8071'
    - '4444:4444'
    volumes:
    - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
    - ./local_addons/:/mnt/extra-addons/
    - ./odoo.conf:/etc/odoo/odoo.conf
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

and Dockerfile (it's pretty simple):

```
FROM odoo:13

USER root
RUN pip3 install remote-pdb pdbpp dateutils xlrd
USER odoo
```

The odoo instance itself works just fine, therefore odoo have to be able to connect to database. But when I try to execute shell like this:

```
docker exec -it odoo_odoo_1 bash -c "odoo shell -d postgres"
```

I have this exception (trace is not full for readability):

```
2019-10-29 14:37:13,094 72 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 13.0-20191022 
2019-10-29 14:37:13,095 72 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf 
2019-10-29 14:37:13,095 72 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons', '/var/lib/odoo/addons/13.0', '/mnt/extra-addons'] 
2019-10-29 14:37:13,095 72 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default 
2019-10-29 14:37:13,272 72 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf 
2019-10-29 14:37:13,377 72 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Initiating shutdown 
2019-10-29 14:37:13,377 72 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown. 
2019-10-29 14:37:13,378 72 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'postgres'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/odoo", line 8, in <module>
    odoo.cli.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/cli/command.py", line 60, in main
    o.run(args)
.....
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 600, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I don't specify postgres host and port explicitly (here is my odoo.conf):

```
[options]

addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo
debug_mode = True

; db_host = db
; db_port = 5432
; db_user = odoo
; db_password = odoo
; db_name = postgres
```

Do you have any thoughts why I can't connect to database?

Answer (score 3):

docker-compose create multiple docker containers one which is running Odoo, the other which is running Posgresql, and so on based on the yaml configuration, actually they are different machines with different ip address. So launching the command:

```
  docker exec -it odoo_odoo_1 bash -c "odoo shell -d postgres"
```

odoo will try to connect to postgres referring to localhost, which in this case is the container which is runnig odoo, but not postgres.
If you specify the parameters --db_host and --db_password should work:

```
  docker-compose exec odoo odoo shell -d <DB-NAME-CREATED-WITH-ODOO> --db_host db --db_password odoo
```

or

```
  docker exec -it odoo_odoo_1 bash -c "odoo shell -d <DB-NAME-CREATED-WITH-ODOO> --db_host db --db_password odoo"
```

**Example**

Create docker compose as in https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/#!:

```
docker-compose.yaml:

  version: '2'
  services:
    web:
      image: odoo:12.0
      depends_on:
        - mydb
      ports:
        - "8069:8069"
      environment:
      - HOST=mydb
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=myodoo
    mydb:
      image: postgres:10
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myodoo
        - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
```

run docker-compose:

```
  docker-compose up -d
```

connect to localhost:8069 and create new DB named "my-test-db", and after log in to shell with:

````
  docker-compose exec web odoo shell -d my-test-db --db_host mydb --db_password myodoo```
````

Answer (score 0):

Odoo `shell` need to run with same configuration as you are using your docker container to start, `/etc/odoo/odoo.conf`. Basically with this command `odoo shell -d postgres` you are running Odoo shell instance without any configuration, and Odoo application database selected as `postgres`, change it to the following

```
docker exec -it odoo_odoo_1 bash -c "odoo shell -c /etc/odoo/odoo.conf -d ODOO_DATABASE_NAME"
```

If you turn on debug mode, Odoo database name is displayed right after the username section on top right corner inside parenthesis.

[image: Database name]

Comment: It doesn't work this way
`docker exec -it odoo_odoo_1 bash -c "odoo -c /etc/odoo/odoo.conf shell -d test"`
gives
`
Usage: odoo [options]

odoo: error: unrecognized parameters: 'shell'`
and
`docker exec -it odoo_odoo_1 bash -c "odoo shell -c /etc/odoo/odoo.conf -d test"`
gives the same error

Comment: It gives the same error with postgres socket.
What exactly do I need to write instead of "ODOO_DATABASE_NAME"?

Comment: database name that you are trying to log into shell with

Comment: "test" was the name of my database, and your answer haven't solved the problem. Thanks for attention, though.

Answer (score 0):

Writing custom Dockerfile resolved the problem (I've written my own Dockerfile for some other reasons, but it did solve my problem with odoo shell).
Here is my local environment if someone is facing my problems:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

# Generate locale C.UTF-8 for postgres and general locale data
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# Install some deps, lessc and less-plugin-clean-css, and wkhtmltopdf
RUN set -x; \
        apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
            ca-certificates \
            curl \
            dirmngr \
            fonts-noto-cjk \
            gnupg \
            libssl-dev \
            node-less \
            npm \
            unzip \
            gcc \
            python3-dev \
            python3-psycopg2 \
            python3-num2words \
            python3-pip \
            python3-phonenumbers \
            python3-pyldap \
            python3-qrcode \
            python3-renderpm \
            python3-setuptools \
            python3-vobject \
            python3-watchdog \
            python3-xlwt \
            xz-utils \
        && curl -o wkhtmltox.deb -sSL https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb \
        && echo '7e35a63f9db14f93ec7feeb0fce76b30c08f2057 wkhtmltox.deb' | sha1sum -c - \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ./wkhtmltox.deb \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* wkhtmltox.deb

# install latest postgresql-client
RUN set -x; \
        echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ buster-pgdg main' > etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
        && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
        && repokey='B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8' \
        && gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "${repokey}" \
        && gpg --batch --armor --export "${repokey}" > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pgdg.gpg.asc \
        && gpgconf --kill all \
        && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" \
        && apt-get update  \
        && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install rtlcss (on Debian buster)
RUN set -x; \
    npm install -g rtlcss

# Download odoo source from github
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" odoo \
        && mkdir -p /odoo \
        && chown -R odoo /odoo \
        && curl -LOk https://github.com/OCA/OCB/archive/13.0.zip \
        && unzip 13.0.zip \
        && mv ./OCB-13.0/* /odoo/ \
        && rm -rf ./OCB-13.0 \
        && rm -rf 13.0.zip

COPY ./requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt

ENV ODOO_RC /etc/odoo/odoo.conf
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/odoo \
        && mkdir -p /mnt/extra-addons \
        && mkdir -p /etc/odoo \
        && touch /etc/odoo/odoo.conf \
        && chown -R odoo /var/lib/odoo \
        && chown -R odoo /mnt/extra-addons \
        && chown -R odoo /etc/odoo/odoo.conf

USER odoo

CMD ["/odoo/odoo-bin"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
    - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
    - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  odoo:
    depends_on:
    - db
    build: .
    ports:
    - '8069:8069'
    - '8071:8071'
    - '4444:4444'
    volumes:
    - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
    - ./local_addons/:/mnt/extra-addons/
    - ./odoo.conf:/etc/odoo/odoo.conf
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

odoo.conf:

```
[options]

addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons,/odoo/addons
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo
debug_mode = True

db_host = db
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = odoo
; db_name = postgres
```

requirements.txt:

```
Babel==2.3.4
chardet==3.0.4
decorator==4.0.10
docutils==0.12
ebaysdk==2.1.5
feedparser==5.2.1
gevent==1.1.2 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version < '3.7'
gevent==1.3.4 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version >= '3.7'
gevent==1.4.0 ; sys_platform == 'win32' and python_version >= '3.7'
greenlet==0.4.10 ; python_version < '3.7'
greenlet==0.4.13 ; python_version >= '3.7'
html2text==2016.9.19
Jinja2==2.10.1
libsass==0.12.3
lxml==3.7.1 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version < '3.7'
lxml==4.2.3 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version >= '3.7'
lxml ; sys_platform == 'win32'
Mako==1.0.4
MarkupSafe==0.23
mock==2.0.0
num2words==0.5.6
ofxparse==0.16
passlib==1.6.5
Pillow==5.4.1
Pillow==6.1.0 ; sys_platform == 'win32' and python_version >= '3.7'
polib==1.1.0
psutil==4.3.1; sys_platform != 'win32'
psutil==5.6.3; sys_platform == 'win32'
psycopg2==2.7.3.1; sys_platform != 'win32'
psycopg2==2.8.3; sys_platform == 'win32'
pydot==1.2.3
pyldap==2.4.28; sys_platform != 'win32'
pyparsing==2.1.10
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pyserial==3.1.1
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.7
pyusb==1.0.0
qrcode==5.3
reportlab==3.3.0
requests==2.20.0
zeep==3.1.0
vatnumber==1.2
vobject==0.9.3
Werkzeug==0.14.1
XlsxWriter==0.9.3
xlwt==1.3.*
xlrd==1.0.0
pypiwin32 ; sys_platform == 'win32'
```

This environment mostly bases on standard odoo image, but I build it from source from github repo.

I'm running shell like this, without specifying odoo config file:

```
docker exec -it odoo_odoo_1 bash -c "/odoo/odoo-bin shell -d ODOO_DATABASE_NAME"
```